# rdist has to be replaced by rsync

Tags: rsync

I have distfile written which has set of instructions to maintain identical copies of files and folders on slaves. I have a task to replace `rdist -f distfile`  to `rsync`, can `rsync` operate on old distfile which was created earlier and used for `rdist` as `rdist -f` option how to replace the `rdist` with `rsync`.

Comment: No, you'll have to start from scratch.  And there are a few things `rdist` can do that `rsync` can't.

Comment: Can I create any distfile similar sort of thing separately and pass it to rsync because we have more than 100 script files where this has to edited

Comment: //distfile example   HOSTS = ( 192.168.200.xx 192.168.200.xx )

DIR = /etc/test/logs

FILES = ( /usr/local/sniff_logs /usr/localsniff_logs)

(${FILES}) -> (${HOSTS})
        except ( ${DIR}/asplhat);

Comment: Read the manual for both, write a parser for `rdist` configs, write out the corresponding `rsync` commands as applicable, and write scripts for what can't be done otherwise.  Alternatively, convince your boss it's a stupid idea...